# MSP430 Ram Overflow

Tags: c, flash, memory, struct, msp430

The MSP430G2553 only has 512 Bytes of RAM but 16KB of FLASH memory.  On this microcontroller, all static/global variables are assigned in RAM under .bss section.  All local variables are assigned in RAM under .stack section.  All dynamically allocated memory variables (malloc) are assigned in RAM under .sysmem section.

I have a need for this MSP430 to keep track of connected devices via wifi.  I have a struct as such:

```
struct dev
{
    char type[20];
    char ipAddress[13];
    char name[20];
    char status[1];
};
```

This struct takes up 54 bytes of memory for each device.  I am planning on having 20+ devices connected that this MSP430 and need to have 20 of these structs.  20 x 54 bytes = 1080 bytes.  This is obviously too big for the 512 bytes of ram.

Is there any way to write these structs into FLASH since I have 16KB of memory to use?  My understanding of FLASH is variables that are only read-only.  These structs will obviously be getting assigned so it is read-write and I am not sure if it is possible.

I don't quite understand why TI would make a device which has 16 KB FLASH and only 512 Bytes of RAM, when all variables requiring read-write operations are stored in RAM.  Seems like it is a waste of space.

I have tried to change these sections .bss/.stack/.sysmem to FLASH in the linker file and the MSP430 will not run like this.  I have also tried to change the size of the RAM and in linker file and change the memory locations adding another 512 Bytes, but it will not run like this either.

Do I have any options here?

Comment: Encode everything, you don't have to save everything as strings, except the name.

Comment: Why do you need 20 bytes to define the type? The `char` type can reference 256 different types, which can be detailed in ROM (or FLASH code), but you should place the field next to the `status` field, or pack the `struct`. Anyway what is the point of `char status[1]`?

Comment: IPv4 only requires 4 bytes, not 13. IPv6 only requires 6 bytes.

Comment: @WeatherVane: 6 bytes would be Ethernet. IPv6 takes 16 bytes actually (128 bits)

Comment: If the values change more than once in a while, you definitively should **not** write them to Flash! Also note that writing to flash requires a special command sequence and first to erase the sector and then program. Both take typically some ms up to 1s to complete (see the datasheet for actual duration). During this time, the CPU cannot execute code from flash, so the whole system stalls.

Comment: @Olaf mybad you are right.

Comment: Note: use `stdint.h` types, not the standard types. Also: I still wonder where you got the 13 `char` IP-address from?

Comment: Can you add some extra harwdware, serial/SPI flash for example, like those little Atmel serial EEPROM beetles?

Comment: " don't quite understand why TI would ...": That is the most common behaviour for MCUs with embedded Flash actually. It even is the same if using external Flash, be it parallel NOR, NAND or serial. Please show me a Flash device you can read while writing.

Comment: That could be a crude coding of IPv4 as `"001002003004\0"`

Comment: @WeatherVane: I see. Who would use such? Either dotted-quad for user-I/O (plus terminator) or binary `uint32_t` as in an IP frame.

Comment: @Olaf the same person who uses `char status[1];`

Comment: @WeatherVane: Fair enough :-}. PC programmers gone bare-metal.

Comment: ... or who does not figure out his system requirements ahead of specifying the chip.

Comment: Sounds like a former boss of mine: "that must not cost more than x€ - see what you can do!"

Comment: @WeatherVane I've bought this MSP launchpad coming with two different chips for 4 bucks  once upon a time. So I guess it is working like this: Wow! A cheap board! Taking it. Now..what can I do with this?

Comment: I've got some PIC16F84 still lying around. Where do I get a webserver for that? Multiprocessor, of course

Comment: "DESCRIPTION... Typical applications include low-cost sensor systems that capture analog signals, convert them to digital values, and then process the data for display or for transmission to a host system." http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430g2553.pdf

Comment: @WeatherVane: "... for transmission to a host system" If it can be one host, why not 20+? Can't be _that_ much more complicated ...

Comment: @Olaf I bleed for him. I've had to write stuff when there *cannot* be enough RAM, yet somehow I managed to mangle it.

Comment: @WeatherVane: In the 80ies/early 90ies PC-RAM compression software was widely spread (it was more a placebo). But, yes, I know the same. But did the rough planning in advance. OP even forgot about other variables and stack. The MSP430 uses a fair amount of stack for interrupts: 14 Registers *2 bytes). But that sounds more like a private project, not job. For that an M0(+) would likely be cheaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write data into the flash memory. The only problem arises when you want to change the data. You can only erase sectors, which have a size of 512 bytes. So you could take two flash sectors from the flash and store data for 10 devices in each sector.
The flash can be read like RAM though, so you don't need some kind of swapping code, you just address each device entry with a pointer.
The last problem is that flash memory has a limit of erase cycles, here around 10000 cycles. So you might also have to write code to distribute the data to different sectors over time, depending on the amount of expected changes and the desired service durability.

Comment: When you say sectors are 512 bytes, are you talking about this particular microcontroller or *all* microcontrollers?

Comment: @FiddlingBits: For the given MCU, it **is** 512 bytes, but the FUG calls it "segments". It is not true for all Flash devices (be it MCUs or discrete).

Answer (score 2):

You can store a *constant* data in the flash/program memory. If you know that some variables/arrays are actually not changing once initialized, you can declare them as `static const` in your code and the compiler will place them in the `.text` section, which is usually going to the FLASH memory. If you have dynamic data that doesn't fit in the memory.. well. You are screwed, unless you can think of optimization (like reusing the same space for different things at different times..). Of course there is a possibility to implement some kind of "swapping" functionality with FLASH, if your part has a programmatic access to the FLASH writing. But it is really not that simple.

And for this:

> I don't quite understand why TI would make a device which has 16 KB
>   FLASH and only 512 Bytes of RAM, when all variables requiring
>   read-write operations are stored in RAM. Seems like it is a waste of
>   space.

You are getting what you are paying for. Every micro has a specific range of applications it is intended for. If this specific micro is not good for your application, probably it is not in that range.

Comment: Yeah.. with this requirement and harwdare, I would have stopped at 'You are screwed' :(

Comment: @MartinJames: There are no problems, but only challenges. Sometimes we feel more challenged than normal.

Comment: @Olaf but sometimes you are losing the challenge :)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No, just the patience. :-)

Comment: @Olaf in that case, I'm glad you're not a surgeon.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good bit of extra room you can free up in this struct.

Type `type` field probably doesn't need to be a char array.  You can use a set of symbolic constants with all the possible types.

The IP address also doesn't need to be stored as a string.  Assuming IPv4, you only need four bytes.

`status` doesn't need to be an array of size 1.  A simple `char` will suffice.

So now you have something like this:

```
struct dev
{
    uint32_t ipAddress;   // 4 bytes
    char name[20];        // 20 bytes
    char type;            // 1 byte
    char status;          // 1 byte
};                        // 2 bytes padding, total = 28 bytes
```

It's still not quite enough to fit 20 of these into 512 bytes of memory, but it's better that what you had.

Comment: USA have already run out of PIv4 addresses. For IoT, I'd strongly recommend to use IPv6 actually. (and a `char [1]` does not take more than a `char`. That looks like the pre-C99 version for a flexible array member). Note: the MSP430 is a 16 bit architecture. So padding goes to even addresses, not 32 bit boundary.

Comment: You'll also need a stack in there.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your best option is probably to switch to a more capable chipset. The MSP430 G-line is really meant for extremely low power and low performance applications, Ethernet being neither of those (and certainly not multiple TCP/IP connections at the same time!).

As for why they'd make a chip with a huge Flash space and tiny SRAM, well, Flash is cheap and compact, where SRAM is space-expensive on the die, so TI had to make compromises to deliver that MCU for less than $1. As some of the other answers alluded to, you can use that large amount of Flash to write more code, that can encode/compress/decode/decompress data to/from SRAM.

Another option is to use one of the "Wolverine" series of MSP430 chips. Those use a unified FRAM bank rather than separate Flash and SRAM banks.

Comment: Well, "huge" relative to the RAM; factor of 32 difference.